# Exceptions to zsh correctall feature?

Tags: zsh, autocorrect

I am using the `correctall` option in `zsh`, and I am generally quite happy with it. There are, however, few situations where I find this feature highly annoying.

For example, lets say I have a file `file1.tex` and I want to create a copy called `file2.tex` which I will then edit to make some changes.  I will do

```
cp file1.tex file2.tex
```

only to be told by `zsh` that I might have misspelled `file2.tex` and if I want to correct it to `file1.tex`.

What happens is this: when `zsh` tries to check spelling, it looks in the current directory for a file called `file2.tex`, does not find it, but finds `file1.tex` and assumes that I misspelled `file1.tex`, and asks me if I want to correct that.

That happens to me so often that I actually unset the `correctall` option, and use only `correct`.   However, bad typist as I am, I really miss the `correctall` option.  Thus my my question:

*Is there any way to tell `zsh` not to correct the last argument of the `cp` command?*

(I know I could get the result I want by modifying completion settings for `cp`, but I still want to have completion on the last argument, I just don't want to autocorrect it.)

Comment: I think you can get the result by modifying completion settings for `cp`, without losing completion. Look at the section about `zstyle` in the `zshcompsys` man page, particularly the `corrections` tag. Be sure to report back if you understand what command to issue (I don't).

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks!  That will at least give me a direction in which to look.  Next time I have few days (or perhaps weeks, or months?) with nothing to do,  I will see if i can make any sense of it. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try these.

```
alias cp='nocorrect cp '
alias mv='nocorrect mv '
alias mkdir='nocorrect mkdir '
```

etc.

That's not totally on point as it will disable application of correctall for the entire command, but I think it's a good compromise. Completion (including the _correct completer) and expansion, for example, will still work.

Comment: Thanks.  Although it is not exactly what I was looking for, it seems to be the closest thing that's actually possible.