# How to partially disable the zsh's autocorrect

Tags: zsh, autocorrect

The autocorrection function of zsh is very helpful for me but it does't always gives a proper result.

```
~$ sudo vim somefile
zsh: correct 'vim' to '.vim' [nyae]?
```

Yet what I want is something like the a **never** option that can stop it to correct commands like those forever.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can inform zsh that it should not autocorrect on specific commands by aliasing them with the prefix 'nocorrect' in your .zshrc (example here: https://web.archive.org/web/20110213094724/http://dzen.geekmode.org:80/wiki/wiki.cgi/-main/ZshConfiguration):

```
alias vim='nocorrect vim'
```

Alternatively -- if this whitelisting process becomes too frustrating  -- you can switch autocorrect off entirely with the following in your .zshrc.

For newer versions of zsh use:

```
 unsetopt correct
```

for older versions of zsh use:

```
 unsetopt correct-all
```

Amended to add: here is a previous discussion on this subject - [Exceptions to zsh correctall feature?](https://superuser.com/questions/251818/exceptions-to-zsh-correctall-feature)

Comment: While this works for when vim command is at the start, but doesn't work for commands such as `bundle exec cucumber <some_specific_feature> && bundle exec rspec <some_specific_spec>`. I've added an alias for rspec. Any tips?

Comment: @MartinFoot: if you use oh-my-zsh the bundler plugin may help you: https://coderwall.com/p/weixga

Comment: In the new versions `unsetopt correct_all` changed to `unsetopt correct`

Comment: @antitoxic: I wanted to look up what "new version" in terms of version numbers means, but even in today's git checkout (zsh 5.0.2+31433) the `zshoptions` manpage states for `CORRECT_ALL`: _Try to correct the spelling of all arguments in a line._ Furthermore, both man entries for `CORRECT` and `CORRECT_ALL` didn't changed at least since 2008. So I am missing your point; can you please explain what you leads to your statement?!

Comment: I'd like to add: load order matters! Make sure you add unsetopt after sourcing oh-my-zsh... Wasted a lot of my time.

Comment: I have a sh function, and `nocorrect` doesn't work : `prod() {
  nocorrect heroku $* --app myprodapp
}`. When typing `prod logs` I get `Did you mean log? [ynae]`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I get command not found.

Comment: I don’t think `correct` superseded `correct-all`. Aren’t these two different options?

Comment: `unsetopt: no such option: correct-all` - it should be  `correct_all`.

Answer (score 37):

I think I found a better answer to this.

Im not sure about versions and whatnot, but it seems `correct_all` is supposed to correct commands **and** arguments, while `correct` corrects only commands, therefore eliminating this annoying behaviour.

This is what I have in my config files

```
unsetopt correct_all  
setopt correct
```

Comment: This is the actual answer. `correct-all` doesn't appear to be a real option in any documentation I can find, nor in Real Life. It's `correct_all`. Thanks!

Comment: I have setopt correctall from http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html

Comment: If you use oh-my-zsh, ensure you put the two lines after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` otherwise it does not work. It seems oh-my-zsh will reset option correct_all.

Comment: @Matt `setopt correct` works before the sourcing of `oh-my-zsh.sh`. I do not know what you mean by `reset`: get the old state? Can you show in oh-my-zsh.sh where it is?

Comment: @Timo Did not for me. The  `~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` script do call `setopt correct_all` via `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/correction.zsh`. So doing the `setopt correct ` call before sourcing the `oh-my-zsh.sh` was reverting the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem when using `rspec` via `zeus`, and I'd like to keep auto-correct settings as they seem to work for everything else **except** `rspec`, so I never tried any of the other suggestions above.

What I had to do was `nocorrect` zeus itself :

alias zeus='nocorrect zeus'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable autocorrection using

```
ENABLE_CORRECTION="false"
```

I am using zsh version 5.7.1

Comment: That's probably not doing what you think it does.

Answer (score -1):

In case you use oh-my-zsh:

unsetopt correct_all

will disable all autocorrection.

Setting aliases for exceptions (see link below) does not do the trick for me.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/correction.zsh

Comment: No, it won't. See `man zshoptions`.